# Docker build fails to install pyrfy

Tags: docker, pip

I am trying to build an image with docker containing some pretty simple packages.
Here's the requirements file:

```
autoimpute==0.12.2
numpy==1.19.2
fuzzywuzzy==0.18.0
pymongo==3.11.4
boto3==1.18.65
pandas==1.1.3
pytest==0.0.0
scikit_learn==1.0
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

COPY app.py requirements.txt ./
COPY data data/
COPY models models/
COPY models_autoML models_autoML/

RUN apt install swig
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

COPY dsci1.py ./

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

I get the following error, which is weird since I pulled a project from another collaborator and it is supposed to work. Why is it failing, and what can I do to fix it?

```
#10 18.88   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 18.88
#10 18.88   × Running setup.py install for pyrfr did not run successfully.
#10 18.88   │ exit code: 1
#10 18.88   ╰─> [7 lines of output]
#10 18.88       running install
#10 18.88       running build_ext
#10 18.88       building 'pyrfr._regression' extension
#10 18.88       swigging pyrfr/regression.i to pyrfr/regression_wrap.cpp
#10 18.88       swig -python -c++ -modern -py3 -features nondynamic -I./include -o pyrfr/regression_wrap.cpp pyrfr/regression.i
#10 18.88       unable to execute 'swig': No such file or directory
#10 18.88       error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1
#10 18.88       [end of output]
#10 18.88
#10 18.88   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 18.88 error: legacy-install-failure
#10 18.88
#10 18.88 × Encountered error while trying to install package.
#10 18.88 ╰─> pyrfr
```

Comment: There seem to be a couple of things going on here, are you sure this is the Dockerfile you're actually building? The `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8` image doesn't have `apt`, so this fails at the swig install. If I remove that line, it fails to install your requirements because there is no pytest version 0.0.0 If I remove pytest from the requirements, everything installs as expected.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I substituted apt with yum (plus another install) and it actually works. Here's the new dockerfile. Thank you! ```FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8
#FROM python:3.9-alpine

COPY app.py requirements.txt ./

COPY data data/

COPY models models/

COPY models_autoML models_autoML/

RUN yum -y install swig
RUN yum -y groupinstall 'Development Tools'

RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt -t .

COPY dsci1.py ./

# Command can be overwritten by providing a different command in the template directly.
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]```